# Project organization with Tensorflow.keras. Should one subclass tf.keras.Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I'm using Tensorflow 1.14 and the `tf.keras` API to build a number (>10) of differnet neural networks. (I'm also interested in the answers to this question using Tensorflow 2). I'm wondering how I should organize my project.

I convert the keras models into estimators using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator` and Tensorboard for visualization. I'm also sometimes using `model.summary()`. Each of my models has a number (>20) of hyperparameters and takes as input one of three types of input data. I sometimes use hyperparameter optimization, such that I often manually delete models and use `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` before trying the next set of hyperparameters.

Currently I'm using functions that take hyperparameters as arguments and return the respective compiled keras model to be turned into an estimator. I use three different "Main_Datatype.py" scripts to train models for the three different input data types. All data is loaded from .tfrecord files and there is an input function for each data type, which is used by all estimators taking that type of data as input. I switch between models (i.e. functions returning a model) in the Main scripts. I also have some building blocks that are part of more than one model, for which I use helper functions returning them, piecing together the final result using the Keras functional API.

The slight incompatibilities of the different models are begining to confuse me and I've decided to organise the project using classes. I'm planing to make a class for each model that keeps track of hyperparameters and correct naming of each model and its model directory. However, I'm wondering if there are established or recomended ways to do this in Tensorflow.

**Question:** Should I be subclassing `tf.keras.Model` instead of using functions to build models or python classes that encapsulate them? Would subclassing keras.Model break (or require much work to enable) any of the functionality that I use with keras estimators and tensorboard? I've seen many issues people have with using custom Model classes and am somewhat reluctant to put in the work only to find that it doesn't work for me. Do you have other suggestions how to better organize my project?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass only if you absolutely need to. I personally prefer following the following order of implementation. If the complexity of the model you are designing, can not be achieved using the first two options, then of course subclassing is the only option left.

1. tf.keras Sequential API
2. tf.keras Functional API
3. Subclass tf.keras.Model

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The complexity of my models can be achieved using the Functional API. I'm wondering if subclassing Model would make my project more structured. The tutorials (e.g. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers in Models: Composing layer) seem to suggest that this is sometimes done. For example a recurring block in a deep network gets its own class. Your suggestion for my case would be to keep using functions that return models or plain python classes to organize the project?

Comment: Well it depends: if your objective is neat and quick path to producing a working solution with the present assortment of all the TF wizardry available through tf.keras, then follow along as I suggested. However, if for some reason you actually want to know the inner workings of the models and similarly handcraft that, then although it could be painful, use Model subclassing. I would suggest you to refer to the source code for Dense layers to see and compare that with a hand coded layer in your model. This is a longer path, but with time this will give you more mileage to tweak/develop code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a reasonable thing to do: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models)