# The methods of building a model in general

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Currently, I'm creating models for affective computing and I've seen there are two different approaches of building models in tensorflow.

1. Initialize an empty Sequential() then just put Dense layers into it.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Activation('relu'))
.
.
.
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

2. Taking the outputs of a existing model and put additional Dense layes afterwards

```
model = VGG16.output
model = Flatten()(model)
.
.
.
model = Activation('softmax')(model)
```

I would like to know whether there any difference between the first and the second approach? If yes, which one is proper for which scenarios?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for: ***A rationale behind which approach to use and when***.

You could build a model and train it on some training data from ground-up. Or, you could use a previously trained model and fine-tune it, which is also called transfer learning. You may even use another model's backbone but train it from ground-up (no transfer learning here).

Which one among these you want to use, it completely depends on your use-case.

1. The first code block in your question is used to define model of your choice from ground-up.

   - You could use *Sequential*, *Functional* APIs or even try *Subclassing* if you need to build more sophisticated models.
2. The second code block in your question could be used for any one of the following two:

   1. finetuning a pre-learned network for your specific task (You are essentially transfer learning here).
   2. using the backbone of a network without loading it's weights and train it from ground up.

See this: [Project organization with Tensorflow.keras. Should one subclass tf.keras.Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685407/project-organization-with-tensorflow-keras-should-one-subclass-tf-keras-model/58685507#58685507)

Comment: Thank you very much. That means there is no difference between them in principle, right?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes, because the approach you take is different (like taking different paths from your work to your home, if that is necessary) depending on your use-case. No, because, ultimately what you build is a model that serves your purpose: prediction within an acceptable range of error.